# Как убрать белые полосы safe-area на IPhone для сайта при просмотре в ландшафтном режиме?

Tags: reactjs, веб-программирование, ios, nextjs, viewport

Мы (студенческий коллектив) разрабатываем приложение, просмотр которого возможен только в ландшафтном режиме. Столкнулись с проблемой: белые полосы (безопасная зона) по бокам изображения при просмотре приложения в горизонтальном формате у некоторых пользователей *IPhone*.

Мы просто хотим убрать эти полосы. По [гайду](https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/) от *Apple*, мы добавили *meta-tag* с именем *viewport*, но особых результатов это не дало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приложение всё равно выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ещё странно, что полоса осталась только с одной стороны, хотя раньше была с двух...

[Ссылка на деплой](https://dev--stupendous-tiramisu-445728.netlify.app/panorama?instruction=true)

Что мы делаем не так?

UPD:
Не пробовал на том проекте, но при разработке на Next.js в главном layout.tsx можно задать свойства для viewport. Может поможет.[image: Код viewport metadata]

Comment: Хм, у меня она появляется только при первой загрузке. Если перевернуть телефон туда-обратно, то полоска пропадает.

Comment: Отдельный вопрос зачем принудительно требовать ландшафтный режим…

Comment: @AlexeyTen, Там то ли заказчик так решил, то ли что-то такое, в общем: что имеем, то имеем)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используется app router, то следует добавить этот код в свой app/layout.tsx (nextjs v14.0.3)

```
import { Viewport } from 'next';

export const viewport: Viewport = {
  width: 'device-width',
  initialScale: 1,
  maximumScale: 1,
};
```